# How to create a list inside a list, using elements from one vector, in r

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector, element

I am trying to create lists inside lists using a single vector in R.

I have the vector

```
Conditions = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

and I want a list containing A, B, C and D (no problem). But then I also want those to be lists containing four items named along the lines of: `A vs A`, `A vs B`, ... `D vs C`, `D vs D`, ultimately ending up with a list of four lists (A, B, C, and D) each containing four further lists ('vs' lists) that I can add data frames to.

essentially I want something like this:

```
My list
 |
 |
 |        /- A vs A       /- B vs A      /- C vs A      /- D vs A
 |       /               /              /              /
 |      /- A vs B       /- B vs B      /- C vs B      /- D vs B
 |     /               /              /              /
 ---A-|-------------B-|------------C-|------------D-|                       
       \               \              \              \
        \ - A vs C      \ - B vs C     \ - C vs C     \ - D vs C
         \               \              \              \  
          \- A vs D       \- B vs D      \- C vs D      \- D vs D
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Conditions <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

MyList <- as.list(Conditions) 

for(i in 1:length(MyList)) {
    for(i in 1:length(Conditions)) {
    MyList[i] <- list(paste(MyList[i], 'vs', Conditions[i]))
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. For instance my first item just gets turned from `A` to  `A vs A vs A vs A vs A`.

Edit: for greater clarification I would like,

A list e.g.,

```
Letters
```

That will contain four lists,

`A` , `B` , `C`, `D`

These in turn will contain lists, corresponding to their names:

A: `A vs A`, `A vs B`, `A vs C`, `A vs D`
B: `B vs A`, `B vs B`, `B vs C`, `B vs D`
C: `C vs A`, `C vs B`, `C vs C`, `C vs D`
D: `D vs A`, `D vs B`, `D vs C`, `D vs D`

I will then put a data frame into each 'vs'.

The most helpful answer so far was from MrFlick:

```
lapply(Conditions, function(x) 
  as.list(paste(x, "vs", Conditions)))
```

Which returns:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A vs A"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "A vs B"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "A vs C"
```

...

```
[[4]][[2]]
[1] "D vs B"

[[4]][[3]]
[1] "D vs C"

[[4]][[4]]
[1] "D vs D"
```

All I want is for the list to be empty, and the string to be used as a name. For the element just above I think it would look like this:

```
[[D]][[D vs D]]
    [1] NA        #Data Frame DvsD.Rda to be added here later.
```

Comment: Looking at other answers, mine is the only one that resembles tree you have drawn. Is that actually what you want  (compare to `c("A","A","C","D")`) or to each of the conditions (`c("A","B","C","D")`) ?

Comment: It should be A B C D, I made a mistake, though I thought I had edited it out already.

Comment: ok i have edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logic is always the same, try

```
Conditions = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
L=setNames(as.list(Conditions),Conditions)

L=lapply(L, function(x){
  setNames(vector("list",length(Conditions)),paste0(x," vs ",Conditions))
})

> str(L)
List of 4
 $ A:List of 4
  ..$ A vs A: NULL
  ..$ A vs B: NULL
  ..$ A vs C: NULL
  ..$ A vs D: NULL
 $ B:List of 4
  ..$ B vs A: NULL
  ..$ B vs B: NULL
  ..$ B vs C: NULL
  ..$ B vs D: NULL
 $ C:List of 4
  ..$ C vs A: NULL
  ..$ C vs B: NULL
  ..$ C vs C: NULL
  ..$ C vs D: NULL
 $ D:List of 4
  ..$ D vs A: NULL
  ..$ D vs B: NULL
  ..$ D vs C: NULL
  ..$ D vs D: NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can have $A - A vs A, A vs B, A vs C ... etc, so that I can replace the string with a data frame?

Comment: This is incredibly close to what I want but I can't quite get it to match. would you be able to look at my question again? I have tried to be more specific.

Comment: @SolebaySharp this should answer your question

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do is someting like this :

```
Conditions <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

MyList = lapply(Conditions, function(x) list())
names(MyList) = Conditions

for(i in names(MyList)) {
    for(j in 1:length(Conditions)) {
        MyList[[i]][[paste(i, 'vs', Conditions[j])]] = NA #Put NA or the data frame you want.
    }
}
```

Output :

```
$A
$A$`A vs A`
[1] NA

$A$`A vs B`
[1] NA

$A$`A vs C`
[1] NA

$A$`A vs D`
[1] NA


$B
$B$`B vs A`
[1] NA

$B$`B vs B`
[1] NA

$B$`B vs C`
[1] NA

$B$`B vs D`
[1] NA


$C
$C$`C vs A`
[1] NA

$C$`C vs B`
[1] NA

$C$`C vs C`
[1] NA

$C$`C vs D`
[1] NA


$D
$D$`D vs A`
[1] NA

$D$`D vs B`
[1] NA

$D$`D vs C`
[1] NA

$D$`D vs D`
[1] NA
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear originally, I'm looking for the 'vs' components also to be lists which will be filled with data frames.

Comment: How might you go about putting what has been used as the string as the name for the list? i.e. instead of $D [[4]] [1] "D vs D" it would be $D $D vs D [1] NA (data frame to be put here later).

Comment: I also changed the initialization of `MyList `

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, have a look,

```r
vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

res <- lapply(vec, function(x) {
    out <- expand.grid(x, vec)
    lapply(1:nrow(out), function(y) {
        paste(out[y, 1], " vs ", out[y, 2])
    })
})
str(res)
```

Result:

```
List of 4
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : chr "A  vs  A"
  ..$ : chr "A  vs  B"
  ..$ : chr "A  vs  C"
  ..$ : chr "A  vs  D"
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : chr "B  vs  A"
  ..$ : chr "B  vs  B"
  ..$ : chr "B  vs  C"
  ..$ : chr "B  vs  D"
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : chr "C  vs  A"
  ..$ : chr "C  vs  B"
  ..$ : chr "C  vs  C"
  ..$ : chr "C  vs  D"
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : chr "D  vs  A"
  ..$ : chr "D  vs  B"
  ..$ : chr "D  vs  C"
  ..$ : chr "D  vs  D"
```

Comment: I'm sorry I worded my original question poorly, would you be able to look at it again?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want

```
lapply(Conditions, paste, "vs", Conditions)
```

That's assuming vectors are OK in the list. If you need lists, then you can do

```
lapply(Conditions, function(x) as.list(paste(x, "vs", Conditions)))
```

If you need to give the main list names, use `setNames()`

Comment: I wasn't clear originally, I'm looking for the 'vs' components also to be lists which will be filled with data frames.

Comment: I think actually you have given me something very close to what I wanted I just can't name my lists.

Comment: @SolebaySharp So what exactly do you want the final object to be? Can you include the desired output in the question? Like `list(A=list("a v a"=list(), "a v b"=list(), ...)` etc. And how do you plan to get data.frames in there?

Comment: That text description still isn't precise enough. What's the actual structure you expect? How would you build it by hand for this simple example? What would the `dput()` look like?

Comment: I'm not sure how to build it by hand I was trying automate it because A, B, C and D will change. If they were folders the fist path would look like this: Letters/A/AvsA and would eventually contain a data frame AvsA.Rda. Next would be Letters/A/AvsB/AvsB.Rda and so on. Then when plotting later I am hoping to be able to call specific data frames by name, because I have named and organised them logically.